# Where is the Force.com Flex Zip file referred to in a link in Flex developers guide Nov 9 2012?

Tags: force.com-sites, force.com

I have been searching the web for 2 days and I cannot find the Flex Toolkit for Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 Premium.  The link referred to in the Force.com Flex Developer`s Guide dated Nov 9 2012 is non existant - I end up on the developers Page!!! I can only find a zip file of the old Toolkit dated 2009 in a completely different place.  The Force.com IDE file referred to in Eclipse Market Place does not install and clashes with the Eclipse Java module that is preinstalled in Flash Builder.  Removing that file causes Flash Builder to hang.  Please help I am going nuts!!!!

Answer (score 2):

There are various Flex projects for Force.com, but none are still in active development.  The old Flex for Force.com (aka Stratus or F3) was not updated for the latest version of Flash Builder and hence has some basic compatibility issues unless you are using Builder 4.5 (I believe it was) or below.  This is probably what you are running into - unfortunately to maintain that project required Adobe involvement which no longer exists, and there's nobody working on it internally in Salesforce.com that I know of either.

The link Scott refers to ( http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/AIR_and_Flex_Toolkit ) points to the generic SOAP based toolkit which formed a decent chunk of the Flex for Force.com functionality, but does not includes some of the components or offline syncing.

If you are doing AIR development, you can also use this REST/OAuth library I wrote sometime ago:
https://github.com/joshbirk/Flex-RESTKit

However, there are issues with Adobe's implementation of the Flash Player which means you wouldn't really be able to use it within Visualforce (for example).

Comment: Many thanks joshbirk!!!!
Is there another alternative to Flash Builder within Force.  We need to display line graphs and table graphs within Visualforce and are looking for the best solution to do this.  More help would be highly appreciated. Regards

Comment: SOAP toolkit is going to be the best approach there.  Aside from the link Scott had - you might try:

http://developer.force.com/flextoolkit

Answer (score 0):

The link goes to this page:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/AIR_and_Flex_Toolkit

Sadly, the 2009 build is the latest version. Rumor has it that the Flex team inside of Salesforce has moved on to other projects.

I was still able to develop an app in Builder 4.6 using the 2009 toolkit, but I had to create a new OAuth engine for user login. But after you get a session ID, the old toolkit works like a charm.

Comment: Many thanks Scott!!!! Is there another alternative to Flash Builder within Force. We need to display line graphs and table graphs within Visualforce and are looking for the best solution to do this. More help would be highly appreciated. Regards